# Type Mismatch Array Position Compare Vba

Tags: vba, type-mismatch

I don't understand why I cannot compare an array in VBA. I created an array that starts 0 1 2 3. I added a comparison due to subscript errors trying to compare 0 to 0 - 1 so it can only start comparisons at 1 and continue. Now I'm receiving a type Mismatch 13 and I can't figure out why the data type is different/not working. I'm guessing i in a for loop is not considered an int or something? 
It fails at CoordinatesArray(i) = CoordinatesArray(i-1)

Code:

```
 For i = 0 To NumLines - 1
        coordx1 = (vLines(12 * i + 6))
        coordy1 = (vLines(12 * i + 7))
        coordz1 = (vLines(12 * i + 8))
        CoordinatesArray(i) = Array(coordx1, coordy1, coordz1)
        If i > 0 Then
            If CoordinatesArray(i) = CoordinatesArray(i - 1) Then
                coordx1 = (vLines(7))
```

Comment: A small comment:  I notice you used TimWilliams answer without marking it as correct.  Please go back through your questions and mark those answers that are correct as such, by clicking the check mark by the answer.  If you fail to give feedback other users will stop answering your questions.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to compare each value in the jagged array separately:

```
For i = 0 To NumLines - 1
    coordx1 = (vLines(12 * i + 6))
    coordy1 = (vLines(12 * i + 7))
    coordz1 = (vLines(12 * i + 8))
    CoordinatesArray(i) = Array(coordx1, coordy1, coordz1)
    If i > 0 Then
        If CoordinatesArray(i)(1) = CoordinatesArray(i - 1)(1) And _
          CoordinatesArray(i)(2) = CoordinatesArray(i - 1)(2) And _
          CoordinatesArray(i)(3) = CoordinatesArray(i - 1)(3) Then
            coordx1 = (vLines(7))
```